# Dynamic SPQuery

Tags: wss-3.0, spquery

I want to build search criteria by using SPQuery object that searches a list. On application page, there are two textbox Controls, 2 combobox Controls and 2 people picker Controls. The search criteria is based on user input. Users will use any or all of these Control values to search records. I could not find an efficient way to solve this issue. I need some good links or suggestion to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to dynamic query using CAML..

but u can do using linq query.

for eg.

```
var query = from SPListItem objItem in objSPList.Items
                        where onvert.ToString(objItem["Status"]).Equals("Completed")
                        && Convert.ToString(objItem["ItemType"]).Equals("Current")
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = Convert.ToString(objItem["ID"]),
                            Title = Convert.ToString(objItem["Title"]),
                            Status = Convert.ToString(objItem["Status"])
                        };

foreach(var oItem in query)
{
    //oItem.ID
}
```

you can put create dynamic query after where clause based on condition.

some links are which helps u..

http://corypeters.net/2009/09/querying-a-sharepoint-list-with-linq/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535491%28v=office.14%29.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/156014/How-to-use-LINQ-to-Sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

[CAMLEX.NET](http://camlex.codeplex.com/) is good tool to solve you task.

From documentation: [Dynamic filtering conditions](http://camlex.codeplex.com/documentation)